# Bypass TFS Gated Check-In with Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm working on auotmating a process that involves checking in some data files to a build that has a Gated Check-In process.  In Powershell, I have the code together like so:

```
$pendings = $ws.GetPendingChanges()
if($pendings.Count -gt 0)
{
    $ws.CheckIn($pendings, $checkInComments);
}
```

This code functions perfectly if it's in a manual check-in area, I have all of the DLLs added and so on.  But if the build is Gated, it fails, with:

```
Exception calling "CheckIn" with "2" argument(s): 
"Your check-in could not be completed because it affects the following gated build definitions.
```

I found the following answer for this very question done in C#, but I can't seem to translate it over to Powershell, as I understand, .net methods should be available to me if I have the appropriate DLLs added.

```
var pendingChanges = workspace.GetPendingChanges();
if (pendingChanges.Any())
{
    WorkspaceCheckInParameters parameters = new WorkspaceCheckInParameters(pendingChanges, BuildCommonUtil.NoCICheckInComment)
    {
        OverrideGatedCheckIn = true,
    };
    workspace.CheckIn(parameters);
}
```

Does anyone have an ideas on how I can bypass the gated (permissions assumed) in Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

I checked all over the internet, powershell documentations , MSDN references for code equivalent to "`OverrideGatedCheckIn = true`" for Powershell and all I found was below non working piece of code

```
Write-Host "tf.exe checkin"
        & $tfexe checkin $wsp /comment:"***NO_CI***" 
        /bypass /noprompt /recursive /override:"Auto-Build: Version Update" | Out-Null
```

**Solution**

So, My solution to this problem is moving the assembly versioning files (AssemblyInfo.vb & AssemblyInfo.cs) to a folder called SharedAssembly and excluding them to considering for the GatedCheck-In process.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You *could* try using this when you setup your gated check-in workspace.

- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.ClientCheckInParameters.OverrideGatedCheckIn Property

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.checkinparameters.overridegatedcheckin(v=vs.120).aspx